# Living room LED tape powering opetions

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

i would like to request an expert advice. My intention is to install dimmable led tape on living room ceiling. Ceiling design is on a "Π" design, measuring 5.6m, 6.6m and 3.8m (total 16meters). My LED tape (single color) is standard 12V tape of 14.4watt/meter. My drivers are 2x 150Watt (so that i have a good power margin). I also have power supply from both ends of my "Π" design. 
Now, i am troubled about installation, powering and voltage drops and my questions are as follows:
A. Can i have total continuous 16meters tape, powered on each end from each one transformer? 
B. Also, since i need to have it dimmable, if i connect remote RF dimmer on one side only, will it work?
Many thanks in advance!
Any advice is welcome...
Nick

Comment: Possibly related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105044/can-you-power-led-strips-from-both-ends

Comment: My answer at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105044/can-you-power-led-strips-from-both-ends completely applies here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I have read very carefully this post and i agree it applies, but my particularity is the dimming. If i connect one dimmer on one side, will it have to be full amperage? and will it work? Now, my thinking is to connect directly the strips to the transformers, so no distance between each end of led tape to each transformer.

Comment: Idea is to have one RF dimmer, for both supplies, since each transformer shall be on opposite side. I understand this ring line is a bad idea but i am struggling to find an idea on how to apply single remote dimming mechanism for full length of the led tape, when powers are on opposite sides.